# Why is my code returning False when the if statement criteria are met?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

The goal is to return True if nums (a non-negative number) is within 2 of a multiple of 10.

The test cases that don't work are:
near_ten(19) → True (my code returns False)
near_ten(158) → True (my code returns False)

```
def near_ten(num):
  a = num % 10
  if a <= 2:
    return True
  elif a > 2:
    return False
```

Comment: `19%10` is 9, which is greater than 2. Why don't you check if `a` is greater-than-or-equal-to 8?

Comment: its only false `if 2 < a < 8`

Answer (score 2):

how bout

```
def close_to_ten(num):
    return not (2  < num%10 < 8)
```

Answer (score 2):

You were missing the check for 8 and 9 which are still within 2 of 10.

```
def near_ten(num):
  a = num % 10
  if a <= 2 or a >= 8: # we want to get 0 1 2 and 8 9
    return True
  return False # in all other cases it is False
```

Comment: Got it. Didn't consider 2 less than 10, just from 0

Comment: I am glad that I could help.